# How to refer wikipedia categories in an ontology?

Tags: ontology, foaf

Is it perfectly alright to refer a category resource in an ontology by using wikipedia URI? Like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cuisine for Cuisines? I want to define user interests using FOAF such as:

`<foaf:topic_interest>Cuisines</foaf:topic_interest>`

I'm a beginner, just want to know is it possible to make this association with wikipedia? And if yes then what's the syntax? and if not then what other option do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the association you suggest like this (assuming this is placed in the right place in a valid document):

```
<foaf:topic_interest>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cuisine</foaf:topic_interest>
```

However, it would be more useful to link it to [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/About). DBPedia extracts data from Wikipedia as [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/). The DBPedia wiki contains an [example](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Interlinking) on how to link FOAF to DBpeida URIs. Thus, the example in your question would look like this:

```
<foaf:topic_interest>http://dbpedia.org/page/Cuisine</foaf:topic_interest>
```

With the link representing a dereferenceable RDF description of the URI.

Comment: does it has all the categories of wikipedia? or I'll have to some way check before making a link?

Comment: I believe the Keyword Search API of the [DBpedia Lookup](http://dbpedia.org/lookup) service will allow you to check before making a link. Although, I've never used it.

Comment: slight nitpick - `<foaf:topic_interest>http://dbpedia.org/page/Cuisine</foaf:topic_interest>` should be `<foaf:topic_interest>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cuisine</foaf:topic_interest>` ie. the concept of "Cuisine" rather than the concept of "the dbpedia page about the concept of "Cuisine" " (which is a valid interest - just probably not intended)